# SQLite increment Integer Primary Key and Unique Constraint conflict

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I have a SQLite database.
When writing move rows function, which moves rows from one table to another I need to have a query for incrementing column with name "row" which is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, but there is an error. It is critical to have indexing with row in my task. The condition in example is `WHERE row >= 2` because i am inserting rows from other table into position 2.

`"UPDATE '4' SET row = row + 1 WHERE row >= 2"`

`Error("19", "Unable to fetch row", "UNIQUE constraint failed: 4.row")`

The problem's origin `WHERE row >= 2"` part. How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem's origin `WHERE row >= 2"` part.

I'm inclined to disagree.  The problem is not with which rows are updated, it is with the *order* in which they are updated.

Very likely SQLite will process rows in rowid order, which almost certainly is also increasing order of the `row` column, since that column is an auto-incremented PK.  Suppose, then, that the table contains two rows with `row` values `2` and `3`.  If it processes the first row first, then it attempts to set that row's `row` value to `3`, but that produces a constraint violation because that column is subject to a uniqueness constraint, and there is already a row with value `3` in that column.

> How to overcome this problem?

Do not modify PK values, and especially do not modify the values of *surrogate* PKs, which substantially all auto-increment keys are.

Alternatively, update the rows into a temporary table, clear the original table, and copy the updated values back into it.  This can be extremely messy if you have any FKs referencing this PK, however, so go back to the "Do not modify PK values" advice that I led off with.

Comment: this works for me. One extra question. I still want that my "row" column to be UNIQUE. And it still restrit such query. Probably problem not in the autoincrement.

Comment: @KiskaJoe, you're right that the problem is not in the autoincrement, but you seem not to be getting the main point.  **The problem is that the nature of your update is inherently incompatible with the affected column's uniqueness constraint.**  It doesn't matter that the affected table would satisfy the constraint after all rows were updated (though that's why my workaround works).  SQLite insists that the table satisfy the constraint after each individual row update comprised by your query, and there is every reason to expect that that requirement will *fail*.

Answer (score 1):

First: `'4'` is not a table name. The `UPDATE` statement expects a table name where you have written `'4'`. For example:

```
UPDATE table1 SET row = row + 1 WHERE row >= 2
```

Second: Just do not use `row` as a primary key (or unique key, for that matter) when it obviously is not meant as primary key but as a changing row number. Create a separate column that can be used as primary index of that table instead.